# Uber Api - request status "processing" timeout

Tags: php, timeout, status, uber-api

I created a ride request and have a request_id that was returned in the response. Then I continuously poll the Uber API to get the current status every 3 seconds.

I need to know how many time I have to poll when the status is "processing" ?

Actualy, on the sandbox API, I poll 2 minutes and then if the status is still "processing" I stop the polling.

But when I try to create a new ride request I have this response :

```
HTTP/1.0 409 Conflict 
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Content-Type:  application/json 
{"meta":{},"errors":[{"status":409,"code":"current_trip_exists","title":"The user is currently on a trip."}]}
```

Do I have to  delete the request after the 2 minutes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your ride request on sandbox - it is created with the processing status - and it will stay in that state until you change the status of the trip. On sandbox you can do it by using `PUT /sandbox/products/{product_id}` [endpoint](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/sandbox#modify-sandbox-products-optional). In this document you can see how to change the state of the trip - modify sandbox request. After you modify it - when you poll the Uber API to get the current status - you will see the status change.

You can delete existing sandbox ride requests by issuing a DELETE HTTP call to the sandbox environment. When issued, the sandbox ride will transition into the rider_canceled status.

After that, you will be able to create the new trip with the same access_token.

Take a note that this is applicable only on sandbox. On the production environment, the trip status will change automatically. For the life cycle of the ride request please check this Uber [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/best-practices#the-sandbox).

Comment: Thanks a lot. 

So in production environnement it is not possible that the status stay in "processing"  ? 

Do I not have to do any actions if after 2 minutes of polling the status is still "processing" ?

I want just to make sure that a I will not a have the case that I stop polling but after the ride request is accepted

Comment: This is correct trip will never stay forever in "processing" state - when the first driver accepts the trip status will change. You can use webhooks to get notified about status change so you don't need to constantly check the status of the trip. How to setup and use webhooks you can find in the docunt here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/webhooks

Comment: Is it really possible to book real cabs using sandbox api, without submitting app for production? My ride request doesn't finish in sandbox mode. What should I do?